# searching through joined polymorphic association with table_name defined

Tags: ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

i have two models

```
class Profession < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord

  self.table_name = 'accounts'

  belongs_to :scope, polymorphic: true

end
```

and a query:

```
Profession.joins(:users).where(accounts: {scope: some_scope_variable })
```

when I run that i get

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'accounts.scope' in 'where clause'
```

what i also tried is

```
Profession.joins(:users).where(users: {scope: some_scope_variable })
```

but it also doesnt work and gives similar error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.scope' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 1):

---

According to the documentation, [polymorphic associations rely on two columns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) being present on the model. Example

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thingable, polymorphic: true
end
```

These columns should exist on `users`:

- `thingable_id`
- `thingable_type`

If you want to query them through an association, you may use the columns directly, like:

```rb
Profession.joins(:user).where(users: { thingable_id: 42, thingable_type: 'Foo' })
```

Also, I'd reconsider the name `scope`, since this is used by Rails already.

---

EDIT:

After submitting the answer above, I started understanding your question, sorry about this.

I reproduced it and made it work like this:

```rb
class Profession < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, as: :thingable # <-- this is missing in your case
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'accounts'

  belongs_to :profession
  belongs_to :thingable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now we can do this:

```rb
Profession.joins(:users).where(accounts: { age: (20..30) })
```

The `WHERE`-clause on the joined table is translated to SQL without any magic and checks:

```sql
WHERE `accounts`.`age` BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

Whereas, the `WHERE`-clause on self-columns are sometimes magically modified:

```rb
User.where(thingable: 42)
```

results in

```sql
WHERE `accounts`.`thingable_id` = 42
--                         ^^^ added by Rails
```

So, if we want to filter on any of these polymorphic columns, we do

```rb
Profession.joins(:users).where(accounts: { thingable_id: 111 })
```

Comment: these two columns definietely exist. `where scope: some_scope_variable` works when called on User model

Comment: I see... it seems to be a problem when User has a custom table name... I'll try to reproduce the whole thing now. :+1:

Comment: i read your updated answer and it must be wrong somehow, because this query used to work without table_name declaration(when accounts table was being used by Account model). another thing is to make it work like you said id need to know every possible type which i dont

Comment: im going to solve it by going `Profession.joins(:user).merge(User.where(scope: variable))`. it works then. i think AT has issues using table_name with joined tables

Comment: :+1: I tested your solution, it produces the same SQL query as `.where(accounts: { thingable_id: 111 })`. Nice!

Comment: And again... if possible, I'd try to rename `scope`, as this conflicts with an existing method on AR.